# Chrome Extension, get URL before writting to history

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension, history

In Google Chrome Extension API:

Is it possible to get URL before it is written to history?

I tried:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === "loading") {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

But the URL is still written to history.

Comment: I mean, I need to do something before the URL is written to history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the following two events:

1) `chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigation` from [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation)

and if that doesn't work (still committed to the history), try

2) `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` from [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

But then, it's not clear why you need it. There is an event of adding something to history, namely [`chrome.history.onVisited`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#event-onVisited), and you can delete the visit from there if needed. If you need to redirect the request, this can be done from `webRequest` API.